# iOS: How to get the last user's location, before she/he goes into subway?

Tags: ios, mobile, gps, geolocation, location

My current app needs a feature, which can **get the user's location** even **under subway**.
Since this app will be mainly used in NYC, and under NYC's subway, your mobile has no signal.*(if you use T-Mobile or AT&T)*. So I decide to use this solution:

```
if user not under subway:
    get accurate location
else:
    get location range[start subway station, end subway station]
```

- **The current problem  is:** How to get the "start subway station"
- **The current solution is:** App update the location info in background
  per 10 seconds, when app detects that cannot access internet, app
  stores this "last location" as the "start subway station".

This solution will waste user's a lot of data and battery.
**Is there other better solution for this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a process that stores user's location constantly will drain the phone's battery really fast. Instead I would store a location every x minutes and calculate the nearest subway entrance from the last saved spot. You could even run some code on every location status and use closer time intervals if the user is getting closer to an entrance (to determine if he/she got into the underground)

Comment: great idea to calculate the nearest subway entrance!

Comment: Thanks!. Also, If you have 2 or more entrances nearby you could use where the user's moving to make an educated guess of which of the 2 will s/he pick. Btw what's the app about? (If you can tell). Im intrigued.

Comment: Thanks! @jugutier, since the previous solution of this problem really waste users' a lot of data and battery, your idea direction is really awesome, maybe we can add some path-history-analysis for each user, when we need to decide which subway station they will go into. But before the app released we cannot disclosure the details. Thank you so much!